# UITabBar badge position in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbaritem

Is there anyway to position UITabBar badge? It looks little displaced in iOS7.
In iOS7, it is displaced towards next tab bar item.

I have used a custom tab bar item.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
UIViewController *viewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
CustomTabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[CustomTabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:EMPTY_STRING image: nil tag:2];
[tabBarItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-14.5, 0, 14.5, 0)];
tabBarItem.customHighlightedImage= [UIImage imageNamed: @"icon_on.png"];
tabBarItem.customStdImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_off.png"];
viewController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
```

Comment: where you set badge value?

Comment: I have set the badge value like this:               UINavigationController* navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
    UIViewController* viewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSString* badgeNumber = nil;
    if ([array count] > 0)
        badgeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [array count]];
    
    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = badgeNumber;

Comment: The badge icon was displaced due to tabbar images. Solved the problem.

Comment: Why was your tabbar images? Im having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when using the deprecated methods, **setFinishedSelectedImage** and **withFinishedUnselectedImage**. Instead, use setImage (imageWithRenderingMode) and setSelectedImage (imageWithRenderingMode).