# UITabBar badge position in iOS7 is not right

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbaritem, badge

The badge is not fully visible. it seems as if the other tabbaritem is partially covering it.

This it eh code i used to set the images on the tab bar:

```
selected    = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_new01.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
image       = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_new01.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[tabBarItem3 initWithTitle:@"" image:image selectedImage:selected];
```

I read in several similar posts that is is hue to the images however, nobody explained what is works with the image and how to solve it.

See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wGUFMFlrpwaHdSVzUwSF9fVGs/edit?usp=sharing) screen shot

Sample similar question at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679253/uitabbar-badge-position-in-ios7)

Comment: any good news on this?

Comment: not really. unresolved

Comment: This was resolve. It got to do with the image ize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the image size

Comment: the answer is not clear. what's wrong with your previous image size. and what should be the right dimen for iPhone 5/6/6+?